# How to tell which files are new or have been modified between calls of a script

Tags: bash, find, cron, date

I want to call a shell script regularly, and in it I need to process the files present in a directory tree that are new or that have been modified since the previous call of the script.

My 1st thought is to call the script from `cron` and use `find -type f -mmin ...` with the same time interval.

But I'd prefer if the script was self sufficient and allowed for manual or irregular calls. I can't just do a plain `diff` because I also need the list of modified files.

Maybe store the date of the call somewhere ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `-newer` argument of `find` :

```
-newer reference
          Time of the last data modification of the current file is
          more recent than that of the last data modification of the
          reference file.
```

Your script could then end with a command such as `echo >timestamp`.
To list the changed files do `find -newer timestamp`.

Comment: Warning: there's a time window between processing a file and running `echo >timestamp`. Updating the timestamp after processing many files will possibly extend this window to significant length for some file(s). A change during the window will be missed by the next `find -newer`. Updating the timestamp before processing (but obviously after getting a list of files from `find -newer`) leaves a window for changes that may cause a processed file seem not processed, I guess. I think in general it's hard to do this flawlessly if files may change when the script runs.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: What kind of time window? Disk writes in the memory cache do not count here, since they were already time-stamped.

Comment: Imagine the script needs one second per new (or modified) file. There are 10 new files to process. After processing the first file there will be 9 seconds until `echo >timestamp` runs. This is the time window when a third party program may change the first file and the change will be "invisible" to the next `find -newer timestamp`. It will be "invisible" to every future `-find newer timestamp` until yet another change happens outside unfortunate windows.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Third-party modifications can certainly falsify everything with racing conditions. As long as this script is the only actor, the poster is fine.

Comment: The script is "to process the files present in a directory tree that are new or that have been modified **since the previous call of the script**" [emphasis mine]. How can the script be the only actor?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: If you assume that files are modified continuously and concurrently with this script, then no backup will ever be exact without some locking mechanism for the folder. Just a time window will not be a guarantee of completeness.

Comment: Yes, therefore I wrote "in general it's hard to do this flawlessly if files may change when the script runs". When a file changes when it's being processed (read), it's quite obvious things may go wrong; but this is not exactly what I meant. The OP's problem is "how to tell which files …". My warning states that the method of deciding *if* to process a file is flawed. It's a different flaw and IMO not that obvious. Even if every change is done with [atomic `rename(2)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22823144/10765659), the time window I described exists and may result in the wrong decision.